# How to create register with relation model embeded?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

I'm using `Loopback 3` to create my application, with `Postgres`.

I've created a `many-to-many` usign `hasManyThrough` relation like this:

- Product has many Composition
- Ingredient has many Composition
- Product has many Ingredient
- Composition belongs to Product
- Composition belongs to Ingredient

How can I create/edit a Product with a array of Ingredient's id, like:

```
POST /products

{
  name: "Potato Chips",
  ingredients: [ 5, 7, 3, 20 ]
}
```

And how can I get Product with list of Ingredients embeded?

```
GET /products/1

{
  id: 1,
  name: "Potato Chpis",
  ingredients: [
    { name: "Potato" },
    { name: "Vegetal Oil" }
    ...
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1/** To create a Product with many Ingredients, I suggest to make a custom remote that takes your product in the body along with the ingredients, and make a loop over the ingredients to link them to your product one by one, using the `add` method *(assuming that Product has many Ingredients through Composition)*:

```js
Product.ingredients.add(ingredientData, callback);
```

**2/** To get a Product with its embedded list of Ingredients, you need to `include` the `relation` property to your GET route (example given in reactjs):

```js
const response = await Axios.get(`/api/products/${productId}`, {
  params: {
    filter: {
      include: [
        { relation: 'ingredients' },
      ],
    },
  },
});
```